# How to group data based on quantify timeseries similarity

Tags: python

I want to predict FPData using SIData using deep learning model. but before training I want to group data based on quantify timeseries similarity. then train data based on group data. I want grouping data into 2 group.

```
SIData_1 = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 47.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 47.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 14.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 16.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 46.0, 50.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 39.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 16.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 54.0, 18.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 49.0, 51.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 40.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 16.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49.0, 77.0, 78.0, 48.0, 31.0, 22.0, 46.0, 61.0, 88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 69.0, 75.0, 36.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 77.0, 113.0, 68.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0, 55.0, 63.0, 48.0, 37.0, 51.0, 15.0, 12.0, 68.0, 91.0, 55.0, 19.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 56.0, 49.0, 51.0, 36.0, 35.0, 41.0, 38.0, 40.0, 93.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 16.0, 41.0, 78.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    
])

FPData_1 = np.array([
    [6.59875],
    [6.76239],
    [6.45033],
    [5.79133],
    [5.56692],
    [5.57529],
    [5.67805],
    [5.87954],
    [5.93947],
    [5.80316],
])

SIData_2 = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 121.0, 112.0, 92.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 120.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 121.0, 112.0, 92.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 120.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 121.0, 112.0, 92.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 120.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 121.0, 112.0, 92.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 61.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 43.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 60.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 43.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 60.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 86.0, 85.0, 53.0, 0.0, 0.0, 43.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 58.0, 43.0, 26.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 94.0, 86.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 54.0, 43.0, 49.0, 41.0, 38.0, 13.0, 48.0, 52.0, 120.0, 112.0, 91.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 25.0, 38.0, 100.0, 121.0, 126.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 57.0, 87.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0],
       
])

FPData_2 = np.array([
[39.3875],
[39.3033],
[39.233],
[38.8577],
[39.1549],
[39.52],
[40.4228],
[40.4586],
[40.3507],
[40.7479],
])

SIData_3 = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 71.0, 102.0, 93.0, 32.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 38.0, 6.0, 46.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 71.0, 102.0, 93.0, 32.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 38.0, 6.0, 46.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 71.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 38.0, 6.0, 46.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 38.0, 6.0, 46.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 38.0, 6.0, 47.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 140.0, 74.0, 0.0, 96.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 39.0, 7.0, 47.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 139.0, 74.0, 0.0, 97.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 39.0, 7.0, 47.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 79.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 139.0, 74.0, 0.0, 97.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 39.0, 7.0, 47.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 80.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 139.0, 74.0, 0.0, 97.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 39.0, 7.0, 47.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 76.0, 102.0, 94.0, 33.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 82.0, 1.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0, 116.0, 103.0, 47.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 91.0, 99.0, 76.0, 0.0, 42.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 84.0, 70.0, 60.0, 53.0, 65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 108.0, 124.0, 98.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 30.0, 78.0, 104.0, 80.0, 132.0, 138.0, 137.0, 128.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 14.0, 94.0, 112.0, 136.0, 145.0, 139.0, 74.0, 0.0, 97.0, 73.0, 114.0, 125.0, 39.0, 7.0, 47.0],
         
])

FPData_3 = np.array([
    [5.35265],
    [4.7069],
    [4.94478],
    [5.63455],
    [5.99171],
    [5.25056],
    [5.16239],
    [5.42854],
    [6.04217],
    [6.1847],
])
```

for example if SIData_1 and SIData_3 is group1 so FPData_1 and FPData_3 also group 1
then SIData2 and FPData2 is group 2.

is it possible for grouping data based on quantify timeseries similarity?

Comment: What does "group data based on quantify timeseries similarity" mean?  Can you describe the logic you are trying to implement?  Your data doesn't include any data which is recognized as a time object in python!  What timeseries data are you referencing?